# why inside of loops not processing?

Tags: c++, loops

i know Matlab as a beginner. It works in Matlab but not working in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int birinci, degerbir, sonuc, degeriki, degeruc, degerdort, degerbes;
    int opr = 144;
    int basamaksayisi;
    int i;
    cout << "kac basamakli olsun" << endl;
    cin >> basamaksayisi;
    while (basamaksayisi != i)
    {
        cout << "birinci degeri giriniz";
        cin >> degerbir;
        cout << "deger 1:" << degerbir << endl;
        sonuc = degerbir;
        i = 1;
        cout << i;
        cout << "ikinci deger giriniz";
        cin >> degeriki;
        degeriki = degeriki * 10;
        sonuc = degerbir + degeriki;
        i = 2;
        cout << i;
        cout << "ucuncu deger giriniz";
        cin >> degeruc;
        degeruc = degeruc * 100;
        sonuc = degeruc + sonuc;
        i = 3;
        cout << i;
        cout << "4.deger giriniz";
        cin >> degerdort;
        degerdort = degerdort * 1000;
        sonuc = degerdort + sonuc;
        i = 4;
        cout << i;
        cout << "5.deger giriniz";
        cin >> degerbes;
        degerbes = degerbes * 10000;
        sonuc = degerbes + sonuc;
        i = 5;
        cout << i;
    }

    cout << "degerler sunlardır:" << degerbir << endl << degeriki << endl << degeruc << endl << degerdort << endl << degerbes << endl;
    cout << "degeler toplami" << sonuc;
    return 0;
}
```

why this "i" and other math operations etc. not counting in while loop ? also similar if else loop not working. Just in and count functions working.

i was tried change while loop to if loop. but its not working. loop's inside math processing not working

Here is output.

```
sh -c make -s
./main
kac basamakli olsun
3
birinci degeri giriniz3
deger 1:3
1ikinci deger giriniz4
2ucuncu deger giriniz5
34.deger giriniz2
45.deger giriniz1
5birinci degeri giriniz4
deger 1:4
1ikinci deger girinizsignal: terminated
```

Comment: This code is pretty hard to read. Can you reformat it with proper indentation and use english words for variable names?

Comment: Stack Overflow usage note: Pick one program and focus on it. If you have two problems, ask two questions, assuming the answer to the first question doesn't make the second problem obsolete or obvious.

Comment: `i = 1;`  then  `cout << i;` the `i=2;  then `cout << i;` ...  Why are you even using a variable `i` at all for this. I am confused what you are trying to accomplish. If the code entered the while loop `i` will be 5 after. Whatever `basamaksayisi` is will not change in the loop so the loop will continue infinitely of `basamaksayisi` is not 5. That is if the loop was ever entered because of the uninitialized value of `i`

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code

```
int i;
cout<<"kac basamakli olsun"<<endl;
cin>>basamaksayisi;
while(basamaksayisi!=i)
```

What do you think the value of `i` is here?

No idea about MatLab but in C++ the variable `i` has not been given a value before it is used, which automatically means that this code is bugged.